# Payment methods

Tags: phrase-meaning

I buy  something and will make payment later or 90 days after purchase .Can I say the phrases below to describe this situation? I can tell this with long sentences but sometimes I need to use short phrases. My english teacher said those are grammatically correct but sound a bit weird.

> a purchase with long-term.
>
> a Purchase with deferred payment.
>
> I bought with payment 90 days after invoice.
>
> I bought with payment with a term of 90 days.

Comment: Each of your examples means something slightly different.  The first two leave off the 90 days. Deferred means it does not happen until later. Long-term could mean several payments or one payment at the end. The invoice might not be provided at the same time as the purchase, for example. And a term of 90 days could mean you make payments over 90 days, with the final payment before the end of 90 days. This is describing a contractual obligation, so making it a bit longer and so exact is OK.

Comment: You mean those are grammatical but mean slightly different from what I want to say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two examples might be grammatically correct, but the whole sentence isn't included so I can't answer that.  Examples 3 & 4 would technically be grammatically correct, but don't sound right and convey a different idea than what you are trying to say.  They all leave out pertinent information.

Customarily the purchase would be introduced in one sentence and the payment would be the subject of a different sentence.

For a casual conversation I would suggest something like the following:

> I bought a car today. Payment is due in 90 days.  (This could be combined into one sentence, 'I bought a car today, and payment is due in 90 days").

For a term found in a contract I would suggest the following:

> Payment is due on or before 90 days following the effective date of this agreement.